# extract single cases from array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

An array of records being generated by

```
@signatures = Signature.where('action_id IN (?)', @actions).all
```

will have actions with one or more signatures.

```
Signature id: 1, action_id: 1
Signature id: 2, action_id: 2
Signature id: 3, action_id: 1
Signature id: 4, action_id: 3
Signature id: 5, action_id: 2
```

What ruby instruction can extract just the single cases, based on action_id? `Signature.id = 4` in the above example

Comment: Please restate the question, it’s impossible to understand what you are trying to achieve. Whether you need a `Signature` with `id = 4`, use `Signature.find(4)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@signatures = Signature.where(action_id: @actions)
                       .group('action_id')
                       .select('id, count(action_id)')
                       .having('count(action_id) = 1')
```

Comment: `PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "signatures.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`  Had not mentioned that postgresql was the database.  This might impact syntactic approach...

Comment: Please see an update; unfortunately, I do not have PG on hand to check, but this should work.